# Firefox 10 developer console jumps down the screen when disconnected and the current webpage is interacted with, on Centos 6.3

Tags: firefox, centos, firefox-developer-tools

If I disconnect the developer tools (via the `position` menu and select `window`), and press/hover over buttons or try to press the 'clear' button on the console, on Firefox 10, it jumps down the page.

I can't find a reason, pattern or any documentation for this bug.

Why does this happen, and how can I stop it before it drives me insane,

Comment: Is you can think of a snappier title, be my guest.

Comment: Have you tried other more recent versions of Firefox.  You might have simply ran into an undocumented bug.

Comment: @Ramhound Ha! I'd love to. I have to use it to stay compatible with our users.